# My old passport with US Visa in it was declared lost or stolen

Tags: visas, usa

My old passport  under my nickname with US Visa in it was declared lost or stolen So I wasn’t able to leave. US authorities asked me to get a new passport.
Now i have my new passport with my name in my birth certificate. Can I still travel to the USA?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't think that's a duplicate. There are two issues here: the name change and the fact that the passport containing the original visa was reported lost. The other question only covers one of these things.

Comment: Something strange is going on, here. Passports are usually only issued under a person's official legal name, not under any nicknames. And are you saying that _somebody else_ reported your passport as lost/stolen, even though that passport was till in your possession?

Comment: (It looks like I said "This isn't a duplicate" and then voted to close as a duplicate anyway. Actually, I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", for the reasons I explained, but the Stack Exchange system can't cope with multiple close reasons, so it just picks the most common reason and incorrectly claims that all close voters chose that one.)

Answer (score 3):

You will need a new visa and need proof that you lost your old passport and visa.

From the [gov website:](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/lost-stolen-visas.html)

> Lost or stolen U.S. visas cannot be replaced in the United States. For replacement of a visa, you must apply in person at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate abroad. When applying for the replacement of a visa, you will need to provide a written account documenting the loss of your passport and visa.

Comment: Ok. Actually I was already in the departure area and was asked by the PAL counter that it was reported that the passport i was holding was reported lost or stopen, and that my name was okay, its the passport number that has a problem so i was asked to get a new passport.

Comment: I have my old passport with US Visa under my Nicko and new passport with my name in my birth certificate

Comment: @MaribelleLimsonPineda To be safest, you should get a new visa. Even if you are allowed to travel to the US on your existing documents, you will be asked at immigration why your name is different, and you should expect a long delay or possibly to be refused entry if you haven't got documentation of a name change. Applying for a new visa with your correct name eliminates this problem.